# \thepage vs floats

Tags: floats, page-numbering

I'm writing a report and I want to make sure that each new chapter starts in an odd page. 
So I wrote the following script which I put before each chapter:

```
...    
%-- to make sure that a new chapter starts on the right side (odd page) %
\ifodd \thepage
{\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
}
\else
{}
\fi
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\chapter{Chap_name}
...
```

It works as following:

If the page before my new chapter is odd, it means that I have to add a blank page in order to start to start the new chapter in the next odd page number.

It works fine if the previous page is a normal page.

But when I have a figure in the page before it, which was moved to a new page since it did not fit in the page and there is not text in the page alongside with the float, then this script does not work.

The command `\thepage` returns a wrong page number (apparently it does not increment if the page only contains a float) and so it does not add a blank page in case the last page was indeed odd.

I dont know how to solve this issue. 
any ideas?

thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you checked `\cleardoublepage`?

Comment: Use the class options 'twoside' and 'openright'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remarks:

- `\thepage` can be anything, roman numerals, complex page numbers (`1-2`), …
  However, `\ifodd` only expects an arabic number. Better is the use of the counter value `\value{page}`.
- The output routine is called asynchronous. Therefore at the time of `\ifodd` somewhere it is not clear, what the pages will be. Much more safe is the place at the top of a page.
- Many document classes provide option `twoside` and command `\cleardoublepage`.
  For instance, KOMA-Script classes provide lots of options and commands. Also a chapter usually starts with `\cleardoublepage` if `twoside` is given.

For the standard classes, `\cleardoublepage` can be redefined to set empty headers and footers for empty pages:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{%
  \clearpage % output floats if necessary
  % new page starts here
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\value{page}%
    \else
      \begingroup
        \pagestyle{empty}%
        \hbox{}\newpage
        \if@twocolumn
          \hbox{}\newpage
        \fi
      \endgroup
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```