# I want page 13 to show up as 12+1

Tags: numbering, triskaidekaphobia

I am writing an important document which has ended up being 13 pages.

For superstitious reasons, I want the page number on the last page to show up as "12+1". In other words, I want the page numbers to be:
1, 2, …, 11, 12, 12+1.

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: But you wrote »13« here yourself! Beware!

Comment: And the question is currently at 13 upvotes, I like to imagine this isn't a coincidence.

Comment: @jfbu Update from a multi-stack user: This is on the HNQ.

Comment: (salvaged from comment). This is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87617/how-to-suppress-page-13

Comment: @LiefdeWen You comment got 12 upvotes, so I upvoted it myself again, else nobody will dare.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Define a new counter format:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fixedarabic}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@fixedarabic\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand{\@fixedarabic}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1=13 12${}+{}$1\else\number#1\fi
}
\makeatother

\pagenumbering{fixedarabic}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-50]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 12+1 is much to obvious. I suggest `$\sum_{i=1}^5 i  -3$`.

Comment: For my own understanding, could you comment on the differences between defining a new counter format and only redefining `\thepage` as follows: `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\ifnum13=\value{page}12+1\else\the\value{page}\fi}`? (The latter also works.)

Comment: @Max More general.

Comment: Many thanks! This worked. It was my first time posting a question here and I am amazed how quickly help came. Thank you all!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that evaluates to zero

Comment: @NieDzejkob No, to 12, which is different from 13 anyhow. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg ;-). I should check my sums better.

Comment: @NieDzejkob It depends if one interprets it as $\sum (i-3)$ or $(\sum i) - 3$. As far as I know in mathematics there is not a convention set in stone for the operator precedence of summation symbols.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni True. Still, it is genuinely understood that unless obviously/specifically otherwise, `$\sum a+b = b+\sum a$`.

Comment: [`\ifodd\thepage odd\else even\fi`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=ifodd+thepage) prints “even” on page 13.

Comment: @HenriMenke Nobody should be using `\thepage` for testing with `\ifnum`: what if we're under `\pagenumbering{roman}`? [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69094/4427) to the first listed question in the link clarifies this.

Comment: @egreg I know, that's why I linked the site search to show that people do this and sometimes even recommend this [as an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171675/10995).  Your thing should blow up if used in `\ifodd` to prevent such misuse rather than giving a wrong result on only one page of the document (`\relax\ifnum#1...` should do it).

Comment: @HenriMenke If a user says `\def\fi{\mathop{fi}}` in order to define a math operator, they're on their own. Using wrong tools can lead to harm oneself. A way out could be using `$12+1$`, but this could lead to page numbers being printed differently from the rest of the document; `$\mbox{12}+\mbox{1}$` seems to me quite clumsy.

Answer (score 17):

It could be a complex solution to convert the counter page to "12+1" if the value reach 13, but if only matter when 13 is the last page, why not simply change the footer just before `\end{document}` to "12+1"?.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
aaa 
\setcounter{page}{12} % this is the 12th page
\newpage
bbb
\cfoot{12+1} % this is the 12+1th page 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- this is a quick solution too. The fancy page style created issues for me elsewhere, so I decided to go with the other proposed solution.

Many thanks everyone.

Comment: @AmirAliAhmadi  the `fancyhdr` package allow a ex­ten­sive con­trol of page head­ers and foot­ers so that issues probably can be solved with no effort,  or maybe the footer can be fixed by another method without that package, but without a minimal working example showing these issues is not possible go further.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution sets page 13 as 12+1 in whichever format your page numbering is set to. It uses [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to set the page number in the `C`entre of the footer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=13
   $\mbox{\setcounter{page}{12}\thepage} + \mbox{\setcounter{page}{1}\thepage}$%
   \setcounter{page}{13}%
  \else
    \thepage
  \fi
}

\pagenumbering{roman} % Just as an example

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```